# How can I add a code that is always executed by Waf before exit?

Tags: python, waf

I want to make [Waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) generate a beep when it finishes the execution of any command that took more than 10 seconds.

I don't know how do add this and assure that the code executes when Waf exits.

This should run for any Waf command not only build.

I checked the [Waf book](http://freehackers.org/~tnagy/wafbook/) but I wasn't able to find any indication about how should I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `wscript` module, you can use the Python standard library's [atexit](http://docs.python.org/library/atexit.html?highlight=atexit#module-atexit) to register callables that you want to be called when the process exit.  For example:

```
import atexit
import time

class MayBeep(object):
  def __init__(self, deadline=10.0):
    self.deadline = time.time() + deadline
  def __call__(self):
    if time.time() > self.deadline():
      print '\7'

atexit.register(MayBeep())

... rest of your wscript module ...
```

Of course you may use something better than `print '\7'` for beeping purposes (all the way to full-fledged multimedia extravaganzas, depending on what other Python extensions you import and use), but this code answers the Q's title -- "add code that's always executed on exit".